# How to fetch value from table as per day using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help.I need to fetch value from table as per day from a week using PHP and MySQL.I am explaining my table below.

> db_comment:

```
id   comment  member_id    comment_status   day

1     Hii         52            1            1

2     Hii         52             1            2
3     Hii         52             1            3

4     Hii         52             1            4

5     Hii         52             1            5

6     Hii         52             1            6

7     Hii         52             1            7
```

Here my requirement is for same `member_id` from lower day(`i.e-1`) to higher day(`i.e-7`) if all `comment_status` value is 1 then true will return (`lets say $isComment=true`) with comment value (`i.e-$comm=Hii`) and if any of day `comment_status` value is 0 for same `member_id` then false value will return (`i.e-$isComment=false`) with comment value as blank(`i.e-$comm=''`). I am explaining my query below.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_comment where member_id=52");
```

Please help me to fetch value as per explained above.

Comment: Luckily, the situation never arises.

Comment: @Strawberry : Means which situation ?

Comment: Day in month or increment integer?

Comment: Comment_status is never 0

Comment: @4EACH : Ok.1-Monday,2-TuesDay,...........7-Sunday.

Comment: use group by day

Comment: @Strawberry : I have given one example the Comment_status can be 0 also.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query